# How to run hadoop balancer from client node?

Tags: hadoop, client, hdfs, nodes, load-balancing

I want to ask how can I run the hadoop balancer? I've tried before on the namenode to run hadoop balancer command, but it has no effect at all (my new datanode still empty). I also read that hadoop balancer is not run on namenode but on client node. So what is the client node, how can I configure it, and how can client node access the hadoop file system?

Thanks all, I need your suggest

Comment: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/admin_hdfs_balancer.html

Answer (score 0):

Client node is also know as edge node, Usually all the developers in a organization will not have access to all nodes on cluster. So for developers to accesss cluster usually we will have a Client node. You need to install hadoop-client packages on client node. If you are using cloudera RPM based installation, you can use below command.

```
sudo yum install hadoop-client
```

After client node installation update your configuration files like core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and other required files. Now when you execute hadoop CLI commands, they will be executed on cluster.

Balancer can be run from any node in the cluster.  It can be a client machine/any node in cluster.

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs balancer
```

Regarding newly added datanode, Just check in the namenode  web UI if your node is added ? If you are able to see there, just check logs.

Comment: if I use the cloudera it have provided with the client node installation, but in apache hadoop essential, how can I have client node? Thanks before